# action bar compact height changes when searchitem expand

Tags: android, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

i have `list fragment` in `BaseActivity` and want to implement search functionality. but `action bar compact` height changes while click on search item button

**see below screenshot**

[image]

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.android.bypeople.uber.BaseActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/btn_profile_selector"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_add"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:visible="false"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

**onCreateOptionsMenu** in fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.base, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_add).setVisible(true);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchItem.setVisible(true);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryListener);

    queryListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {       

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {            
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Searching for: " + query + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043202/android-appcompat-toolbar-stretches-when-searchview-gets-focus/31090253#31090253) too.!!

resolved issue after lots of search and found something.

**may help you too.!!**

after add this attribute in `toolbar`

`android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/myPrimaryColor"
android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/myTextPrimaryColor"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```