# search view expanding many pixels to the bottom on click in tool bar

Tags: android, toolbar

!http://s12.postimg.org/5na33aggt/Screenshot_2015_09_25_23_04_51.png

the link above shows the problem i am facing...i am using the tool bar in kitkat version and in the v-19 styles.xml file the windowTranslucentStatus attribute has been set to true...the status bar and the tool bar are showing as it is expected but when i expand the search view widget the tool bar expands down the bottom..

my v-19\styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

my app_bar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   app:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
   app:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   app:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   app:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layout_width="match_parent">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and my activity layout where tool bar is included

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar">
</include>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardlistplaces_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

if anyone can help me it will fully appreciated...

Comment: I had the same problem. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30767524/4964603) answer that worked for me.